# How were the constants chosen in round 2 and 3 in MD4?

Tags: hash, md4

Just reading [Ron Rivest's explanation of MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320) the hash uses two round constants one $ \text{5A827999}$ on round $2$ and the other $\text{6ED9EBA1}$ on round $3$.

I think they are supposed to be hex representation of square root of $2$ and $3$. But $\sqrt{2} = 1.\text{6A09E667F} $ and

$\sqrt{3} = 1.\text{BB67AE858}$

which are very different from the the values given. Any ideas?

Comment: ok [this](https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/120/420/the_md_message_digest_algorithm.pdf) one might have a better view and explanation.

Comment: If you can find a straight answer in there then self-answering the question is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, but I did not find the answer, the numbers don't add up. And I really appreciate anyone with any suggestion.

Comment: Still stuck but new development. The book "Donald E. Knuth. Seminumerical  Algorithms, volume 2, page 660" is mentioned [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-38424-3_22.pdf) just after the constants. So I tried to find the book but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the solution myself in [here](https://github.com/veorq/numsgen)

It says

> SHA-1 was designed by NSA and uses the constants 5a827999, 6ed9eba1, 8f1bbcdc, and ca62c1d6. In case you haven't already noticed, these are hex representations of $2^{30}$ times the square roots of 2, 3, 5 and 10.